# How do I get my main image to stretch the full length of the screen?

Tags: images, post-thumbnails, headers, css

I have been working on Twenty Sixteen WordPress theme and I accidentally changed something that is affecting my featured/header image. It used to stretch the full length of the screen but now it doesn't.

Can someone take a look and possibly help fix this issue? It was working correctly before.

Answer (score 3):

You learned a valuable lesson: **do not mess with the original theme files**. Learn [how to build a child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) and you will always be able to return to the original, working theme if any accidents happen.

So, to answer your question 'can someone take a look?' - yes, someone probably could, but that would just help you out until the next time you make a mistake.

The best way to approach this is reinstall the original Twenty Sixteen theme and redo your adaptations in the correct, child theme way.